# recording conversations without consent and playing the recordings to others

Tags: arizona

I live in Arizona a retirement community and was on my porch recently having a conversation with a friend. During the conversation, I said some negative comments about the manager and the maintenance man. My neighbor recorded our conversation without my knowledge or permission; he then played it to the manager and the maintenance man and several other residents. Now my friend and I are being ostracized by several residents. My question is do I have a case against my neighbor for illegally recording my private conversation and, if yes, what type of attorney do I contact? Thank you

Comment: Was the neighbour a party to the conversation or an eavesdropper?

Answer (score 1):

This is [legal in Arizona](https://www.azleg.gov/ars/13/03005.htm), which is a "one-party consent" state. That means that as long as one of the parties to a communication (the guy doing the recording) consents, the recording is legal. What that precludes is the government planting a bug and recording the conversation (but they can send in an agent wearing a wire who is a participant).

Comment: Surely the neighbour was an eavesdropper, not a party to the conversation. Doesn't that change things?

Comment: I don't see that that conclusion is supported by the postulated description of the event. Let's see if more details come out regarding what that person was doing.